# Where is Google Voice and Video installed?

Tags: macos

After I have installed some programs I can't find them to open them. I have looked in…

- the **Applications** folder
- the **Utilities** folder
- **About this Mac** → **More info** → **System report** → **Software** → **Installations** as another user explained, and I can I see the program but I cannot open it from this window.

The program I am specifically looking for is called Google Voice and Video, if that matters?

What am I doing wrong? How can I open a program after I have installed it?

Comment: How exactly did you download and install the applications? If you could describe the steps you took in some details (maybe redo them in order to find out what you did) it might be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You've already looked in the standard spots for application installs (Applications folder, Utilities folder,etc...).

However, if you've installed [Google Voice and Video](http://www.google.com/chat/video) (aka Hangouts), you won't find an application to run (on OS X or Windows). This is a plugin for your web browser - not a standalone application.

Read [here](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/159499?hl=en) for details - but in short, you should run the installer (you've likely already done this), then quit and restart your web browser (Safari, Firefox, or Chrome - whichever you use). The features of Google Voice and Video will then be functional, and you can then use video chat with other Google Video users.

Answer (score 3):

From [this article on uninstalling Hangouts](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/161994?hl=en), we can deduce the install location is

```
/Library/Application Support/Google/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller.app
```

You can uninstall it (which is why I found this article) by running

```
/Library/Application Support/Google/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller
```

Answer (score 1):

If the program is on your hard disk you can search for it with the loupe/glasses symbol in the top right of the screen. Click on it and type the name of the program. It will start to populate a list below with suggestions. If you spelled the program correct it will appear in the category **Programm**. Just hit enter and you should be fine.

[image]

Note that this is only one of many possibilities to start a program. But in mine opinion the best if you do not know where the program is on your hard drive.

Comment: Somewhat useful, but this Google plugin is not directly executable.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, the location of all chrome extensions (and Hangouts is extension) is like in the image:

[image: The location of Chrome extensions]

Or here:

[image: 2nd location of Chrome extensions]

So it opens new tab and you should be able to find it and make sure it is enabled, like in this image:

[image: Chrome extensions with Hangouts highlighted]

It should automatically start, but if it does not, restart Chrome, or delete and reinstall the extension from google site.

Answer (score 0):

Google Voice and Video is implemented as a plugin.  On Mac OS X, plugins go here:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins
```

If you look in that directory, you will see that there are two files added:

```
googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin
o1dbrowserplugin.plugin
```

Also in the following directory there are two applications:

```
/Library/Application Support/Google
```

Applications:

```
GoogleTalkPlugin.app
GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller.app
```

Running the uninstaller will remove the files.